# OpenAuth.RequestAuthentication() throws NULL Ref in VS2012 Web-Forms template

Tags: oauth, visual-studio-2012, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to get OAuth to work with the Visual Studio 2012 Web Forms templates. I have followed the instructions from Scott's video:

http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/videos/oauth-in-the-default-aspnet-45-templates

But its throwing `NullReferenceException` in `OpenAuthProvider.ascx.cs Page_Load()`, here:

```
OpenAuth.RequestAuthentication(provider, redirectUrl);
```

Which when you delve into the details it shows that it's being thrown from        `DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.OpenAuthSecurityManager.RequestAuthentication(String returnUrl)`

However, when I new up from a MVC4 template it works like a dream.

Has anyone encountered this?

EDIT: It's clearly an environment issue on my laptop, tried on an alternative and had no problem. I suspect it may be down to me installing VS2012 Ultimate RC, then installing RTM Professional on top of that - though a clean re-install didn't change anything.

Comment: Yes an environment issue...the code broke for me after I installed VS2013 along side VS2012 SP3.  See below.

Answer (score 3):

I also hit this problem and wrote up a short post on how to fix it.

The short version is the `providerName` is being passed as "Facebook" or "Google" through the template. The `AuthenticationClientManager.GetProviderByName()` method is expecting `"facebook"` or `"google"`.

http://wasntnate.com/2012/10/openauth-requestuthentication-nullreference-exception-explained/

Comment: #wasntnate's code that essentially does a ToLower() will fail for the ProviderDisplayName="Microsoft" because the required ProviderName="windowslive".  See below

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this can happen when you instantiate the `OpenAuthSecurityManager` class via its `OpenAuthSecurityManager(HttpContextBase)` constructor, or its `OpenAuthSecurityManager(HttpContextBase, IAuthenticationClient, IOpenAuthDataProvider)` constructor if you pass `null` in as the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is slightly modified **OpenAuthProviders.ascx.cs template** for Net 4.5 Webforms that handles the issue by inserting code to get the `ProviderName` from the `ProviderDisplayName` (and not doing a ToLower). It handles the case of the `Microsoft` `windowslive` `ProviderDetails` where ToLower() from "Microsoft" to "microsoft", as suggested above, will not work because "windowslive" is needed. This change is robust and handles the "Google" to "google" case as above as well. Upon install of VS2013 along side of VS2012 SP3, something broke. VS2013 has a new Identity Model, so IMHO this VS2012 code is deprecated.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        var provider = Request.Form["provider"];
        if (provider == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var redirectUrl = "~/Account/RegisterExternalLogin";
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl))
        {
            var resolvedReturnUrl = ResolveUrl(ReturnUrl);
            redirectUrl += "?ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resolvedReturnUrl);
        }

        //  **after install VS2013 alongside of VS2012 SP3, needed to add this:**
        IEnumerable<ProviderDetails> details = OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.GetAll();
        foreach (var d in details)
        {
            if (d.ProviderDisplayName.Equals(provider, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                provider = d.ProviderName;
                OpenAuth.RequestAuthentication(provider, redirectUrl);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code solved my error..

```
IEnumerable<ProviderDetails> details = OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.GetAll();

foreach (var d in details)
{
    if (d.ProviderDisplayName.Equals(provider, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        provider = d.ProviderName;
        OpenAuth.RequestAuthentication(provider, redirectUrl);
        break;
    }
}
```